# php png image transparency

Tags: php, drawing

I have been working with some code to draw a circle but I am having problems with removing the black background from the shape. I am using imagecopyresampled for its AA features in order to draw a smooth circle, so I can't use a different drawing function. Thanks.

```
<?php

$img_2 = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

$red = imagecolorallocate($img_2, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($img_2, 0, 0, $red);


//set circle values
$xPos = 50;
$yPos = 80;
$diameter = 40;

$img_1 = imagecreatetruecolor(($diameter + 2) * 2, ($diameter + 2) * 2);

$green = imagecolorallocate($img_1, 0, 255, 0);

//draw the circle
imagefilledarc($img_1, $diameter+1, $diameter+1, ($diameter + 2) * 2, ($diameter + 2) *      2, 0, 360, $green, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagecopyresampled($img_2, $img_1, $xPos, $yPos, 0, 0, $diameter+2, $diameter+2, ($diameter + 2) * 2, ($diameter + 2) * 2);


header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img_2);
imagedestroy($img_1);
imagedestroy($img_2);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this:

```
$img_1 = imagecreatetruecolor(($diameter + 2) * 2, ($diameter + 2) * 2);
imagesavealpha($img_1, TRUE);
imagefill($img_1, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($img_1, 255, 0, 0, 127));
```

Or this:

```
$img_1 = imagecreatetruecolor(($diameter + 2) * 2, ($diameter + 2) * 2);
$red = imagecolorallocate($img_1, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($img_1, 0, 0, $red);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the first option doesn't seem to work, while the second option fills in the entire img that the circle is being drawn in, so you no longer see a colored circle, but just a colored square.

Comment: Tested both with PHP 5.4.6 (local) and 5.3.13 (2 different servers). The first version makes the backgound transparent, the second one makes it red. I'm filling the background so the circle should be visible. I assume you put the code in the right place i.e. right after you create $img_1. Right?

Comment: I swear I put it there last time and it didn't work. The first one works fine, thanks. Damm I feel stupid.